# Gazebo 1.9.1 does not cast shadows on COLLADA meshes

Tags: collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I rendered this image with Gazebo 1.9.1, ROS Hydro, and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

[image description http://wunderkammerlab.com/examples/no-shadows-received.jpg](http://wunderkammerlab.com/examples/no-shadows-received.jpg)

The robot casts shadows, and the robot and terrain receive them, but the starting platform and the chair (both COLLADA meshes) do not, but should. I thought there might be a problem with my SketchUp-generated starting platform DAE file, so I put the chair from /opt/ros/hydro/share/gazebo_plugins/Media/models/chair/models/Chair.dae into the scene. Is there an element that I need to add to my DAE files in order for them to receive shadows, or is receiving shadows on DAE meshes a missing feature in OGRE or Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4283/gazebo-1.9.1-does-not-cast-shadows-on-collada-meshes/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 247 on 2013-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

More information on this topic will be put in this issue [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/839/gazebo-191-does-not-cast-shadows-on).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0